# ImageMagick not working in ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, imagemagick, moviepy

I have installed ImageMagic to overlay the text on the video clip. But it shows the follwoing error How to resolve this issue?

###### Create a TextClip with the transcript text

```
    text_clip = TextClip(segment_transcript, font=TEXT_FONT, fontsize=TEXT_SIZE, color=TEXT_COLOR)
    text_clip = text_clip.set_position(TEXT_POSITION).set_duration(cropped_clip.duration)
```

### Error:

convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `@/tmp/tmp8geu2egw.txt' @ error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3706. convert-im6.q16: no images defined` PNG32:/tmp/tmpns_g05qt.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229.
.
.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect

Comment: You need to edit your policy.xml file.  The TextClip software is trying to do something that is not allowed in the policy.xml file.  I have no clue what it is unless you are trying to write to /tmp and it does not have permission for that.  You should not be writing or putting images in /tmp.

Comment: @bilal - it would be great if you could provide a bit more context on how you use textclip, i.e. providing details on how others can try your snippet on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using imagemagick's convert trying to print text to an image. I think this solution might work for you as well, because it looks like it tries to use a path like `@/tmp/tmp8geu2egw.txt` which is blocked in the policy.

I found an example here for my problem (see below):
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/401#issuecomment-278679961

The TLDR is:

1. look for your policy file: `identify -list policy | head` --> run this in command shell;
2. edit the policy file, namely comment out the following line:

```
<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" />
```

After your edit, it should look like this:

```
  <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
  <!--<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/> -->
```

For rendering text, following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138804/how-to-transform-a-text-file-into-a-picture, I tried:

```
convert -size 1500x2500 xc:white -font "Ubuntu-Mono" -pointsize 12 -fill black -annotate +15+15 "@ascii_art.txt" -trim -bordercolor "#FFF" -border 10 +repage image.png
```